# In C# HttpResponse, when does the response stream starts to be sent to the client?

Tags: c#, .net, stream, httpresponse

I am using streams in my http response and was wondering when the stream starts to be sent to the client that sent the request.
I thought it was sent when the response was returned but one of my colleague was arguing that it would be better to start sending it when the body stream is updated (when i do the CopyToAsync in my code below) but then, he was wondering how it was possible to set the headers afterward.
If anyone has deep knowlodge about the way stream are handled with http reponse, I am pretty curious to know the answer and I couldn't find reliable info online.

Here is the code that started the debate.

```
HttpResponseData response = httpRequest.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK);
using (FileStream file = new FileStream(outputPDF, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
{
    await file.CopyToAsync(response.Body);
}

response.Headers.Add("Content-Type", "application/pdf");
return response;
```

Comment: Why bother with those details if you can just use a [`File()` result](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.mvc.controllerbase.file?view=aspnetcore-8.0)?

Comment: If you really want to implement it manually you should use the `Response` property of `ControllerBase`. Set `Response.StatusCode` and `Response.ContentType` at the start of your controller method and then copy your data into the `Response.Body` stream. `StatusCode` must be set at the start as it cannot be changed after you started writing into the body. I'm not sure about `ContentType`. I'm certain `File()` will do all that for you automatically though. The return type of the controller method should be a plain `Task` or `void`.

Comment: use wireshark on your local machine and check what happens while debugging. That's the best way to see what's going on between the client and the server

Comment: Header are ALWAYS sent first, that's how HTTP works, so you can't update headers after the body has started. Notice that Content-Length is not set when the body is of unknown size. The initial part of the body /could/ be sent along with the header, but it's not guarenteed, and is up to the OS to sort out.  You *may* get away with setting the headers after the body, if the body is small, and is buffered in memory, for large streams, this will not happen.

Comment: @GoodNightNerdPride The question doesn't say it's ASP.NET Core MVC.
As for the question: yes, you can only send headers then body, as Neil said.

Comment: @Neil There are trailing headers these days that can be sent after the body in a chunked response. Not that they are needed here, but "always sent first" isn't really correct anymore. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Trailer